# I've done this much, now can someone tell me how to take the records and put into a list so that i can access the records by choice?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
namespace HW
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Employee
        {
            int join_year;
            int age;
            string dept;

            public void getval(int join_year, int age, string dept)
            {
                this.join_year = join_year;
                this.age = age;
                this.dept = dept;
            }

            public void showval()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Joining year of Employee is: {0}", this.join_year);
                Console.WriteLine("Age of Employee is: {0}", this.age);
                Console.WriteLine("Department of Employee is: {0}", this.dept);
            }
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            Console.Write("Enter Joining Year: ");
            int join_year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Age: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Department: ");
            string dept = Console.ReadLine();
            emp.getval(join_year, age, dept);
            emp.showval();

        }

    }
}
```

So yeah basically over here I'm adding the values and they are getting printed too. Now I just want to take these records add it into a list or array so that I can access the records by choice.

Comment: You need a List<Employee> myEmployeeList = new List<Employee>(); iterate until something (get a negative join year for example) and over each iteration do a myEmployeeList.Add(emp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand it right, you want to do this.

```
List<string>() list = new List<string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       switch(i)
       {
          case 0: list.Add(join_year.ToString());
              break;
          case 1: list.Add(age.ToString());
              break;
          case 2: list.Add(dept);
             break;
       }
    }
```

it is pretty simplistic, but will do the job.

Comment: I assume the OP wants a list of Employees, not a list of properties of a single one